# Python command line "-c" quirk

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

executing this statement considers the all commands after the ":" in the for loop

```
python -c 'for a in range(10):print(a);x=123;print(x)
```

I want to indicate to Python interpreter that "x=123;" and after are out of the loop...

?any clues...

Comment: What shell are you on? On  bash, type `python -c 'for a in range(10):print(a) <newline> x=123;print(x)`. Bash does not run the command until the string is completed.

Comment: cant use <newline(s)>...

Comment: I don't know if you can do that with -c args, but you could use echo and pipe. `echo -e 'for a in range(10): print(a)\nx=123\nprint(x)' | python`

Comment: Considering white space is one of Python's "defining" features, I honestly don't think this is doable without using newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html:

> -c 
>   Execute the Python code in command. command can be one or more statements separated by newlines, with significant leading whitespace as in normal module code.

So if your shell is any of bash, sh, or ksh, you should be able to simply format your code as normal, as long as it's fully within the single quotes (ie. Fully indented, carriage returns, etc.).

Comment: See @ZEE's comment concerning newlines.

Comment: As I said, this is the only way to do this, without something like `python -c 'for i in range(10):print(i)if i==0:x=123;print(x)`. +1.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere ZEE's comment obviously was submitted while I was typing my response (the difference is within three minutes).

I certainly hope I didn't get downvoted because people were too lazy to look at that.

Comment: I upvoted your post. I don't know who downvoted. I don't even remember what ZEE's comment was.